# Set extra servlet class path on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Is there a programatic solution for adding a class path (other than the trivial `WEB-INF/classes`) for servlet 3.1 annotation scanning to a Tomcat 9 embedded server? Without using any XML, WAR or WEB-INF folder.

I got this far but I don't know how to proceed without a WEB-INF or WAR artifact:

```
static void startServer() {
    Tomcat server = new Tomcat();
    server.setPort(7070);
    StandardContext context = (StandardContext) server.addWebapp("", "/");
    WebResourceRoot resources = new StandardRoot(context);
    resources.addPreResources(new DirResourceSet(resources, "/WEB-INF/classes", "build/classes/main/java/", "/"));
    context.setResources(resources);
    server.start();
    server.getServer().await();
}
```

This is my solution for Jetty:

```
static void startServer() {
    final Server server = new Server(7070);
    final WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext("/", "/");
    context.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] { new AnnotationConfiguration(), new WebInfConfiguration() });
    context.setExtraClasspath("build/classes/main");
    server.setHandler(context);
    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, the only missing thing is that you need to provide the custom path for the `lib` folder (where the application jar files reside and to be loaded into Tomcat server) as part of the `DirResourceSet` constructor call, i.e., `resources.addPreResources(new DirResourceSet(resources, "/your_own/lib", "build/classes/main/java/", "/"));`

For more details on `DirResourceSet`, look at the API [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/webresources/DirResourceSet.html)

Comment: But I don't have a `lib` folder, my root folders are `gradle, src, build`. Should I find where Intellij Idea and Graddle put my dependencies?

Comment: yes, add the folder path where the JAR files are located